# How to refresh time (Carbon) every 1 second in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am creating a cms app where a user can post their own, of course!

The problem I am facing is when using Carbon. I am using Carbon to make the `created_at` readable to humans using `diffForHumans()`. However, the time updates only when I refresh the page.

How can I dynamically refresh the time (Carbon) without having to refresh the page?

Comment: Use Javascript; PHP (and subsequently `Carbon`) are Server-Side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon is a PHP package, and PHP *renders* your templates into HTML/CSS only *once* as a response when the user requests for a particular page.

What you're looking for instead is to implement this counter in Javascript. Javascript actually runs on the client's browser, whereas PHP is only run on the server itself.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! I want to refresh that specific element i.e. in my case `<span>` every second using javascript. Any solution regarding this issue?

Comment: Look into `moment` which is Javascript's equivalent of `Carbon`. Use a `setTimeout` function to rerun the counter every second. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much @DylanPierce!